# Check whether input belongs to list of intents or not in IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-watson

I have build Intents and Entities in IBM Watson Assistant. Now I need to build a client chat UI and get the response based on my input.

Please let me know:

1. save the context and pass it back to Watson Assistant
2. If I don't build dialog in IBM Watson how can I build dialog logic in my .net client application. I mean how to check my input belongs to the list of entities or not ?

Harsha.